# Вывод папок, файлов по порядку

Tags: php, циклы, файловая-система

Как вывести папки и файлы в таком продяке
.. - директория назад
ПАПКИ - директория папок всех друг за другом
ФАЙЛЫ -директория файлов всех друг за другом

в даный момент у меня всё хаотично в разброс

Вот мой код

```html
             <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="example2_info">
              <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                  <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Тип</th>
                  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending">Название</th>
                  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort column ascending">Дейтвие</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <div id="updateMe">
                  <?php

$dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Открыть заведомо существующий каталог и начать считывать его содержимое
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                    echo '<tr role="row" class="odd">';
                    if (filetype($dir . $file) == 'dir' && $file == '.' || $file == '..') {
                      echo '';
                    }
                    else if(filetype($dir . $file) == 'dir'){
                       echo '<td><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></td>';
                       echo '<td><a href="/backEnd/view/cms/pages/documents/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></td>';
                       echo '<td><a href="/backEnd/model/drive/delTree.php?dir='.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$file.'&url='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</a><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="rename" onClick="reply_click(this.value)" value="'.$file.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-rename">Переименовать</button></td>
                  </tr>';
                    }
                    
                      
                     
                     }

                  }

             
        closedir($dh);
    }
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                    echo '<tr role="row" class="odd">';
                    if (filetype($dir . $file) == 'dir' && $file == '.' || $file == '..') {
                      echo '';
                    }
                    else if(filetype($dir . $file) == 'dir'){
                      echo '';
                    }
                    else {
                      $info = new SplFileInfo($file);
                      $spl = $info->getExtension();
                      if($spl == 'tiff' || $spl =='jpeg' || $spl =='bmp' || $spl =='jpe' || $spl =='jpg' || $spl =='png' || $spl =='gif' || $spl =='psd'){

                         echo '<td><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></td>';
                         echo '<td><button id="zoomImg" type="button" onClick="zoom();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-zoom" value="/backEnd/view/cms/pages/documents/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</button></td>';
                         echo '<td><a href="/backEnd/model/drive/delTree.php?dir='.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$file.'&url='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</a><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="rename" onClick="reply_click(this.value)" value="'.$file.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-rename">Переименовать</button></td>
                  </tr>';

                      }
                      
                     else if($spl == 'docx' || $spl =='doc' || $spl =='dotx' || $spl =='dot' || $spl =='rtf' || $spl =='txt' || $spl =='pdf'){

                       echo '<td><i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i></td>';
                       echo '<td><button id="zoomDoc" type="button" onClick="zoomDoc();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-zoom" value="/backEnd/view/cms/pages/documents/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</button></td>';
                       echo '<td><a href="/backEnd/model/drive/delTree.php?dir='.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$file.'&url='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</a><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="rename" onClick="reply_click(this.value)" value="'.$file.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-rename">Переименовать</button></td>
                  </tr>';

                      }

                      else if($spl == 'xls' || $spl =='xlsx' || $spl =='ods' || $spl =='csv' || $spl =='exel'){

                       echo '<td><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i></td>';
                       echo '<td><a href="/backEnd/view/cms/pages/documents/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></td>';
                       echo '<td><a href="/backEnd/model/drive/delTree.php?dir='.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$file.'&url='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</a><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="rename" onClick="reply_click(this.value)" value="'.$file.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-rename">Переименовать</button></td>
                  </tr>';

                      }
                      else {

                       echo '';
                    
                      }
                     
                     }

                  }

                }
        closedir($dh);
    }

  


                ?> 
              </div>                 
              
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <tr role="row">
                  <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Тип</th>
                  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending">Название</th>
                  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort column ascending">Дейтвие</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
```

код рабочий покажет содержимое папок и файлов

Comment: Делаете слепок файлов и каталогов в массив. Потом сортируете собственной функцией как вам нужно. Потом выводите на экран

Comment: Мало того, что код грязный, так еще и не понятно, что значит по порядку, они и так должны быть по порядку, как идут в папке.

Comment: @And как в file zila к примеру